# Need help with formulating LINQ query

Tags: linq

I'm building a word anagram program that uses a database which contains one simple table:

```
Words
---------------------
varchar(15) alphagram
varchar(15) anagram
(other fields omitted for brevity)
```

An alphagram is the letters of a word arranged in alphabetical order. For example, the alphagram for OVERFLOW would be EFLOORVW. Every Alphagram in my database has one or more Anagrams. Here's a sample data dump of my table:

```
Alphagram   Anagram  
EINORST     NORITES
EINORST     OESTRIN
EINORST     ORIENTS
EINORST     STONIER
ADEINRT     ANTIRED
ADEINRT     DETRAIN
ADEINRT     TRAINED
```

I'm trying to build a LINQ query that would return a list of Alphagrams along with their  associated Anagrams. Is this possible?

---

**UPDATE: Here's my solution based on the suggestions below! Thanks all!**

```
using (LexiconEntities ctx = new LexiconEntities())
{
    var words = ctx.words;

    var query =
        from word in words
        where word.alphagram == "AEINRST"
        group word by word.alphagram into alphagramGroup
        select new { Alphagram = alphagramGroup.Key, Anagrams = alphagramGroup };

    foreach (var alphagramGroup in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alphagram: {0}", alphagramGroup.Alphagram);
        foreach (var anagram in alphagramGroup.Anagrams)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Anagram: {0}", anagram.word1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean linq to SQL?

Comment: Actually, its a Silverlight/RIA Services app, so I believe it uses  Linq-to-Entities. I'm a bit of a n00b with this.

Comment: I do have an Entity Data Model in my solution that was generated from my database table. My model contains one Entity called "Word" which contains the properties "Alphagram" and "Anagram" (among others). I thought that perhaps it was possible to do some sort of self-joining Linq query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = anagrams.Select( 
    a => new {  
           Alphagram = a.ToCharArray().OrderBy(s => s).ToString(),  
           Anagram = a  
       }).toList();
```

A totally new answer...

You seem to need a groupby query look at [How to: Group Data (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896341.aspx).

this should accomplish what you want...

I did a testy with LINQ and this works...

```
    var words = new List<Word>() 
    { 
        new ConsoleApplication1.Word("EINORST", "NORITES"), 
        new ConsoleApplication1.Word("EINORST", "OESTRIN"), 
        new ConsoleApplication1.Word("EINORST", "STONIER"), 
        new ConsoleApplication1.Word("ADEINRT", "ANTIRED"), 
        new ConsoleApplication1.Word("ADEINRT", "DETRAIN"), 
        new ConsoleApplication1.Word("ADEINRT", "TRAINED")
    };

    var q = words.GroupBy(w => w.Alphagram).Select(w => new { Alphagram = w.Key, Anagrams = w.Select(p => p.Anagram).ToList() }).ToList();

    foreach (var item in q)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Alphagram : {0}, Anagrams = {1}", item.Alphagram, String.Join(",", item.Anagrams));
    }
```

Comment: The GroupBy was the key! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var words = new List<Words>() 
    { 
        new Words("EINORST", "NORITES"), 
        new Words("EINORST", "OESTRIN"), 
        new Words("EINORST", "STONIER"), 
        new Words("ADEINRT", "ANTIRED"), 
        new Words("ADEINRT", "DETRAIN"), 
        new Words("ADEINRT", "TRAINED")
    };       


    var result = words.GroupBy(w => w.Alphagram, w => w.Anagram)
                      .Select(w => new { 
                                            Alphagram = w.Key, 
                                            Anagrams = w.Where(p => w.Key.ToCharArray().SequenceEqualUnOrdered(p.ToCharArray())).ToList() 
                                       } 
                             )
                      .ToList();


public static bool SequenceEqualUnOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(first).SetEquals(second);
}
```

Is it what you are looking for? It is LINQ to Objects. You may want to use LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entites to fetch your records into your objects and then use the above-mentioned LINQ-to-Objects query over the already-fetched object collection.